# DELETE query won't completely remove record

Tags: php, mysql

I have been building a simple message board script, and have started writing a script named `delete.php`, where the user can input his/her password to delete the message.  The message is stored with 4 values: `id`, `name`, `password`, `timestamp`, `message`.

The problem I am having is the DELETE query I am using will not completely remove the record.  It will remove the `name` and `message` fields, but the row still exists with `id`, `timestamp` and `password`.  So on my messageboard, rather than the message being deleted, theres a blank message with a timestamp.

I can delete the entry in PHPMyAdmin, but it won't work from my PHP script.

```
$db_connection->query("DELETE FROM 'messages' WHERE 'id' = ".$m_id.";") 
    or die($db_connection->error);
```

`$m_id` stores the ID number of the message.

No errors are returned, and I cannot access the Apache error log.

Comment: Should be `$db_connection->query("DELETE FROM messages WHERE id = ".$m_id) or die($db_connection->error);`

Comment: Post Apache's error log.

Comment: BTW either the delete works and the row is gone or it doesn't. delete does not clear cells.

Comment: Guess what? It cleared cells.

Comment: Maybe you have an update trigger running or something like that?

Comment: @RhysNorton: We are just trying to help you. And I can see no attitude here. Please calm down. Jorge is right - delete just does not clear cells. It has to be something else. Thats just a fact.

Comment: Sorry, but when i was asked to post "the damn Apache log". It seemed like someone was getting their knickers in a knot. My mistake if im wrong. About to post screen shots.  Would love to know how im not constructive.

Comment: @RhysNorton: You are right. We don't like swearwords here. I did not see that. (Has it been edited in?)

Comment: Ok, cant post screenshots yet, so heres a link: http://rhysnorton.com/messageboardtest/beforeandafter.png

Comment: @RhysNorton: Did you run the delete statement in PHPADMIN or in PHP code?

Comment: for that screen shot i used php code and copied the query straight out of phpmyadmin

$db_connection->query("DELETE FROM `rhysnort_messageboard`.`messages` WHERE `messages`.`id` = ".$m_id) or die($db_connection->error);

Comment: The screenshot is the same result I have ended up with so far no matter how many different variations of the query I have tried.  I am starting to think it maybe something else entirely.

Comment: Did you try a hardcoded id? `DELETE FROM rhysnort_messageboard.messages WHERE id = 18` for testing?

Comment: Are you looking at the correct DB and DB schema?

Comment: Yeah. The database only has one table "messages". Is there another mysqli statement other than $db_connection->query?

Comment: I don't know. Am no MYSQLI expert. Maybe you are executing another PHP code accidentally?

Comment: It has to be something im doing with my php.  I played around with my table settings, changing the storage engine etc, same deal.  direct SQL queries work fine but in my script, no joy.  Ill back track and see if i can figure out what i messed up.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. It means alot.

Comment: Joining the conversation a little late so maybe I'm missing something - but those *are* inverted commas ('), not backticks(`)!

Answer (score 1):

It may well be the `";"` which is hampering your query, at the end of your statement here:

```
("DELETE FROM 'messages' WHERE 'id' = ".$m_id.";")
```

And as noted in the comment section, table names do not need quotes around them

A typical `DELETE` statement should be composed of a simple query like this:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM messages WHERE id='$m_id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Although, using `mysql_` function would be a very bad idea, since they are deprecated/not maintaned. In which case, you should learn `PDO` / `mysqli`

Comment: Also, messages should be without quotes since it is the tablename. Still, I can't imagine how this could cause a peculiar problem like this.

Comment: ok so doing all of the above, still no luck.  It's really weird.

Comment: @RhysNorton Try again, with updated approach, and see your errors.

Comment: If ID is an integer it doesn't need to be quoted.

Comment: Same results.  Tried a number of syntax variations.  No go.

Comment: Just run a simple customized query in your page, `DELETE FROM messages WHERE id=1` just to make sure, if the problem is not from your database.

Comment: Either the row get's deleted, or it doesn't. I have never heard of half a row being deleted. Something else ought to be wrong, or you have looked at it wrongly.

Comment: @RhysNorton You keep on saying, `same issue` but, you need to tell us, if you are getting errors or now, or if something is getting/deleted or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$db_connection->query('DELETE FROM messages WHERE id = ' . $m_id ) or die($db_connection->error);
```

If it doesn't work you can do 2 things:

1) Look at Apache's error log.

2) When you delete the row in PhpMyAdmin it often shows you the query used.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the screenshot you provided in the comments, and one possibility is that the existing record really is deleted, but a new one is added by a different piece of code. Without seeing all of your code, I can't tell if this is truly the case. It's something to look for, of course, in addition to making sure you don't have any triggers. Another possibility is that your delete statement isn't actually running at all, but another piece of code is updating that record and setting some of the columns to NULL/blank.